# How do I defeat the "Death Star" (Orkulus Star Base)?

Tags: sins-of-a-solar-empire, sins-of-a-solar-empire-rebellion

My fleet, which has destroyed all other enemy fleets it has encountered (including their capital and Titan ships) and has colonized the capital home world of two different players (random normal AIs), was on its way to one of the enemy Vasari player's planets. Upon appearing from phase space into this planet's gravity well, my [fleet admiral](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Gial_Ackbar#Supreme_Commander_.284_ABY.E2.80.9323_ABY.29) uttered "It's a trap!"*

My fleet was welcomed by the Vasari "Death Star"* (Orkulus Star Base). My fleet engaged it and the remaining planet defense structures (the enemy didn't have much of its fleet left). I then found out that we were no match for it; most of the non-Titan and non-capital ships have been destroyed, and I had to order the retreat of some of the nearly destroyed capital ships.

[image]

I have managed to sneak in a Raloz Heavy Contructor and build an Argonev Star Base in the planet's gravity well that contains the Orkulus Star Base, and tried to retreat to its position once it was made and get it to attack the Orkulus Star Base, but alas, it too has been destroyed, along with some of my capital ships.

Screenshot before it was destroyed:
[image]

My fleet includes 6 capital ships (levels ranging from 1-8), and a Ragnarov Titan (level 1), and around a two dozen combination of Cobalt Light Frigates, Stilat Corvettes, Garda Flak Frigates and Percheron Light Carriers. It has faced and destroyed all other enemy ships, which includes enemy capital ships and higher level-Titan ships, that it has encountered but it can not fight this Death Star menace.

---

Before I load an earlier auto-save, I would like to know: What is the weakness of the Orkulus Star Base? Where is its reactor?* Any pro-tips in destroying this starbase? Who is the "Luke Skywalker" of the TEC Rebel fleet?* How can he use the Force?*

Note: I'm playing as TEC Rebel, in the *Rebellion* expansion.

<sup>* (Star Wars reference/joke)</sup>

Comment: As an aside, looking at the images you'll want some flak frigates to accompany your capital ships the next time they go on an excursion like these. Looking at them empire tree, it seems like the enemy have a large number of hangers in the system, whose bomber's weapons are strong against capital ships and large cruisers.

Comment: @YiJiang'sEvilClone I had a few Flak Frigates (maybe they weren't enough, though) but along with the other cruisers and frigates, they were destroyed too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need the anti-structure cruiser, introduced in *Entrenchment*, which acts as hard counters to Starbases and other defensive structures. The TEC's is the [Ogrov Torpedo Cruiser](http://sinsofasolarempire.wikia.com/wiki/Ogrov_Torpedo_Cruiser), which is basically a giant moving missile platform that is ridiculously good against structures (including Starbases) and nothing else.

[image]

The Starbase you were facing appears to be very well upgraded, which means that you need a good number of these, plus a fleet to protect these against any other ships in the gravity well since they can't defend themselves.

Comment: @Shadur If my memory serves me right (it's been a very long time since I played) the torpedo cruiser is literally useless against anything that is not a structure, since it is incapable of targeting anything else

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to hard counter star bases.  As Yi Jiang pointed out, anti structure cruiers work really well.

The other way to counter them is to have massive amounts of fighters and bombers.    Bombers, especially is the universal counter to all star bases as they all lack anti fighter capability and must rely on their squadrons (assuming it has them).

Note the star base, while mobile, is quite slow so you can easily out pace it using either strategy as the anti structure cruisers have a really long range.

Answer (score 2):

The orkulus is just straight up tough. That is all there really is to it. orgovs work. Also. You could have killed it if your titan was leveled more. As titans grow in level, they get much tougher. The trick to titans is to pick 1 ability only to begin with. For the Ragnarov I recommend snipe. at level 1 put one point into snipe, and one into the weapons upgrade (directly beneath snipe) Then at level 2, put one point into armor and one into anti matter. Then alternate this pattern. When you reach level 6 put one point into over charge. Then at level 9 your titan should look something like. this

0-4-0-2
4-4-4
Then you just pick either of the two abilities left to put 2 points into. Also playing on a map with lots of neutral colonies is good. Expand with your cap ships. but as soon as you get your titan out, begin to take out all defenders with just your titan before sending in the cap ships.

Experience is split between all ships in the gravity well who can earn it. So sending the titan by itself makes it level up a lot faster. Once it is a high enough level, you can take on most AI fleets with it by itself, and easily handle starbases too. even a fully upgraded orkulus. The strategy is the same for every titan EXCEPT the vorastra titan (vasari loyalists) In which case you need all 3 of its main abilities, and so forgo putting points into the anti matter. So it should look more like.

4-4-2-2
4-4-0
Or something along those lines. But a high level titan can handle starbases easy. Even orkulus. Just remember to bring flak. and if you think your titan desperately needs support, send it with frigates and cruisers until it is level 10. Hope it helps a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Bombers, the Ogrov are to situational. 
Bombers > Titans
Bombers > capital ships
Bombers > Structures

Ogrov > Structures

See my point.